# How to trace HTTP request/response in iPad?

Tags: ipad, http, safari, firebug

I am using an iPad and I wanted to trace HTTP request/response just like viewing Net Tab in Firebug/Firefox in windows machine. I am using Safari browser in iPad, is there any HTTP trace I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a PC on the same network you could install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on it, and allow Fiddler to accept external connections and set it as a proxy on in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up mitmproxy or Charles HTTP Proxy.